# Set exact spacing value between rows in array environment

Tags: math-mode, spacing, arrays

I'v aware of this method for increasing or decreasing the spacing in `\begin{array}` environment

```latex
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
```

but is there any way I can set the specific dimension value, exactly one `\jot` for example?

Comment: it uses `\baselineskip` so set that locally to whatever you want (`\jot` is too small that's usually the increase, not the value)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle isn't `\jot` the default value space for all display amsmath environments?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle btw, `\setlength{\baselineskip}{4cm}` doesn't seem to do the thing. It only adds space before the array, but not between its rows.

Comment: ah well yes it uses ht and dp  of `\strutbox` which is re-calculated on a size change but not  if you simply set the length sorry for being misleading.

Answer (score 1):

You may try [tabularray](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package: option `stretch=0` removes the struts, and option `rowsep=0.5\jot` sets the exact spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[ \begin{tblr}{stretch=0,colsep=5pt,rowsep=0.5\jot}
  \tan x  & \cot x   \\
  \frac34 & \dfrac45 \\
  \cos x  & \sin x   \\
\end{tblr} \]

Also you can define a new environment for this:

\NewTblrEnviron{myarray}
\SetTblrInner[myarray]{stretch=0,colsep=5pt,rowsep=0.5\jot}

\[ \begin{myarray}{lc}
  \tan x  & \cot x   \\
  \frac34 & \dfrac45 \\
  \cos x  & \sin x   \\
\end{myarray} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]