# Change anchor of \rule

Tags: math-mode, line-spacing, rules

I'm still trying to [set the exact space in `array` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/645513/213149) and I think I got close to the desired goal. I found out that I can redefine `\@arraycr` in such a way that it doesn't include `\arraystretch` multiplier in there.

Here's what I have so far

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath} %solution should be compatible with these packages 
%\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\arraystretch{0}
\def\@arraycr{\cr\rule{1pt}{1cm}}
\makeatother

\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
a=b & 111111 & d \\
2\dfrac222 & 3 & 444
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The width of `\rule` was set intentionally to visualize it (later I'll set it to `0pt`).

As you can see, the anchor of `\rule` is the baseline, i.e the rule grows from the baseline, but I'd like it to be growing from the very top of the whole line, like so

[image]

so that the actual space between lines is the specified `1cm` in this case.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below adds a default optional value for `\\` used in `array` environment, so that `\\` is the same as `\\[\arrayrowsep]`, where `\arrayrowsep` is a newly provided length.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} %solution should be compatible with these packages 
\usepackage{array}

\renewcommand*\arraystretch{0}

\newlength{\arrayrowsep}
\setlength{\arrayrowsep}{1cm}

\makeatletter
\def\@xarraycr{\@ifnextchar[\@argarraycr{\@argarraycr[\arrayrowsep]}}
\makeatother

% visualize row sep
\newcommand\myrule{\rlap{\smash{\rule[-1cm]{1pt}{1cm}}}}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}[t]{ccc}
    a\myrule =b & 111111 & d   \\
    2\dfrac222  & 3      & 444
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**: In response to OP's follow-up request, now

- `\\` == old `\\[\arrayrowsep]`
- `\\[<sep>]` == old `\\[\dimexpr\arrayrowsep+<sep>]`

Note this changes more of the default behavior and implementation of `\\` in `array` environment. Use as your own risk.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} %solution should be compatible with these packages 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color} % for visualizing row sep only

\renewcommand*\arraystretch{0}

\newlength{\arrayrowsep}
\setlength{\arrayrowsep}{1cm}

\makeatletter

% before, in latex kernel or array.sty
% \def\@xarraycr{\@ifnextchar[\@argarraycr {\ifnum 0=`{}\fi\cr}}
\def\@xarraycr{%
  \@ifnextchar[\@argarraycr{\@argarraycr[0pt]}}

% before, in array.sty
% \def\@argarraycr[#1]{\ifnum0=`{}\fi\ifdim #1>\z@
%   \expandafter\@xargarraycr\else
%   \expandafter\@yargarraycr\fi{#1}}
\def\@argarraycr[#1]{%
  \expandafter\@argarraycr@i\expandafter{\the\dimexpr\arrayrowsep+#1}}

\def\@argarraycr@i#1{\ifnum0=`{}\fi\ifdim #1>\z@
  \expandafter\@xargarraycr\else
  \expandafter\@yargarraycr\fi{#1}}

% visualize row sep
\newlength{\myrule@ht}
\newcommand\myrule[1]{%
  \setlength{\myrule@ht}{\dimexpr#1\relax}%
  \rlap{\smash{\rule[-\arrayrowsep]{1pt}{\arrayrowsep}}}%
  \ifdim\myrule@ht=\arrayrowsep
  \else
    \ifdim\myrule@ht>\arrayrowsep
      \rlap{\smash{\textcolor{blue}{%
        \rule[-\dimexpr\myrule@ht]{2pt}{\dimexpr\myrule@ht-\arrayrowsep}}}}%
    \else
      \rlap{\smash{\textcolor{red}{%
        \rule[-\dimexpr\arrayrowsep]{2pt}
            {\dimexpr\arrayrowsep-\myrule@ht}}}}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}[t]{ccc}
    a\myrule{1cm} =b & 111111 & d   \\
    2\dfrac222       & 3      & 444
  \end{array}
  \qquad
  \begin{array}[t]{ccc}
    a\myrule{1cm+1ex} =b & 111111 & d   \\[1ex]
    2\dfrac222       & 3      & 444
  \end{array}
  \qquad
  \begin{array}[t]{ccc}
    a\myrule{1cm-1ex} =b & 111111 & d   \\[-1ex]
    2\dfrac222       & 3      & 444
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Almost perfect. How can I improve that to support `\\[1ex]` additional spacing inside `array` so that `1ex` adds to the current `\arrayrowsep`?

Comment: @antshar See answer update. The added patch to `\@argarraycr` is more fragile and will be broken if any other packages overwrites relevant `array` internals.

Comment: Looks like you made more effort on implementing the visualization rule than on the actual problem. I appreciate that. It's perfect now! Thanks.

Comment: @antshar :D Yes and it's fun.